# Is there a way to allow my bot to check DMs and post them in a channel in my server?

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js, dm

How would I make my bot send a message to a specific channel with the message when someone DMs the bot? I was thinking about webhooks, but I’m not sure if that’s the right way to go.

Comment: You mean receive a dm on discord and send it to one of your discord server?

Comment: I want it to receive a DM, and send it to a channel in my server.

Comment: From where you want to receive a DM?

Comment: From the bots DMs.

Comment: Have you checked webhooks?

Comment: Yeah, but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.
Now how?

You have first to get the dm message. The [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) has the property `channel` which represent the channel the the message was received in. This property can be of 3 different types, all extending from [`Channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel) which have a `type` property.
This `type` property can have 6 values:

- dm - a DM channel
- group - a Group DM channel
- text - a guild text channel
- voice - a guild voice channel
- category - a guild category channel
- news - a guild news channel
- store - a guild store channel

And from the property [`Message.channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=channel) have this indication:

> Type: `TextChannel` or `DMChannel` or `GroupDMChannel`

So here we have 3 possible result for `message.channel.type`: `"dm"`, `"text"`, `"group"`.

Once you've checked if the message is a dm or not, you have to copy it to your server. Again, the `Message` type have interesting properties for us: `content` and `attachments`.

The way to handle attachments is a bit more complicated than the content itself. You'll have to look for the type [`MessageAttachment`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment) and use its property, as `url`.

But for `content` it's really easy, it's just a string. So we just have to get our channel and send the message.

In the example below, I get the guild and the server by using their ID. You can hardcode them, put them in a json file, in a database or get them in your message and make the dm a command, like:
`+send ID a message with many words`.

```js
let channelID = "X";
let guildID = "X";
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if(message.channel.type === 'dm'){
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor(client.guilds.get(guildID).members.get(message.author.id).displayName, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
    .setColor('#FAA')
    .setDescription(message.content);
    client.channels.get(channelID).send(embed);
  }
});
```

[image]
[image]